# Syntax error with a bash script

Tags: bash, syntax

I have been stuck trying to solve this error for 2 days, but I could not figure out where exactly the error is. Could you please help me with this little tiny error?

```
#!/bin/bash

ntests=10
param_vertexes=10
param_pop=10

echo -e "\nExecution of parallel with 8 threads for $ntests times."
par8_time=0
for i in $(seq $ntests); do
    output=$(./parallel -t 8 $param_vertexes $param_pop)
    echo $output
    par8_time=$par8_time+$(echo $output | cut -d' ' -f6)
done
par8_time=$(echo $par8_time | bc)
echo "Total Iteration/Time: $par8_time"
echo "Speedup of 8 threads: $(echo -e "scale=10\n"$par8_time/$seq_time | bc)"
```

I keep getting the same error

```
Execution of parallel with 8 threads for 10 times.
Sequential iterations / time = 23.642725
Sequential iterations / time = 23.860021
Sequential iterations / time = 23.703970
Sequential iterations / time = 23.513577
Sequential iterations / time = 23.728710
Sequential iterations / time = 23.790608
Sequential iterations / time = 23.590524
Sequential iterations / time = 23.612470
Sequential iterations / time = 23.653072
Sequential iterations / time = 23.675878
Total Iteration/Time: 236.771555
   (standard_in) 3: syntax error
   Speedup of 8 threads:
```

As you can see, the **only** problem with my script is `syntax error` which has not allowed the script to show the speedup factor.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You never set `seq_time`, so the expression `bc` is trying to evaluate is "236.771555/", which gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a=$(echo -e "scale=10;$par8_time/$seq_time" | bc)
echo "Speedup of 8 threads: $a"
```